# Как у созданного объекта QPainter получить его QPaintDevice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt5, рисование

Я пишу простой векторный графический редактор. Опираясь на иерархию классов, которую выдал преподаватель.

Вся работа с объектами (линии, прямоугольники, эллипсы) доступна только через класс Editor.

То есть я создаю QImage на виджете окна, потом создаю QPainter на его основе, после передаю QPainter в Editor (который организует работу объектов всех остальных классов). На виджете определеются только функции для mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent, mouseReleaseEvent и кнопки выбора фигуры. Ну и paintEvent.

Всё, что мне теперь нужно -- это получить доступ к созданному QImage в глубине моей иерархии классов, чтобы выполнить заливку QImage перед очередным вызовом отрисовщика. (Всё это нужно, чтобы рисовать фигуры протяжкой: следуя за движением мышки, координаты отрисоки меняются, нужно стереть предыдущую отрисовку и нарисовать всё заново)

Как мне сделать это? Есть ли у объекта QPainter функция, возвращающая его QPaintDevice?

Гугл мой вопрос не понимает, в документации по QPainter я не вижу ничего такого.

Comment: Думаю, будет вам интересно: https://github.com/gil9red/fake-painter

Comment: Сохраняйте QImage в полях виджета: `self.image = QImage(...`, тогда картинка не потеряется. А по поводу вашего вопроса, у painter'а есть метод device: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#device

Comment: @gil9red спасибо! то, что я искала)

Comment: Хорошо :) отметьте тогда мой ответ как правильный. Кст, интересно было бы посмотреть на тот редактор :) Пользуетесь гитхабом / битбакетом / гитлабом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть ли у объекта QPainter функция, возвращающая его QPaintDevice?

Так и называется [device()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#device). В консоли будет один и тот же объект:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

img = Qt.QImage(200, 200, Qt.QImage.Format_RGB32)
print(img)

painter = Qt.QPainter(img)
print(painter.device())
```